# Regarding the way to add a directory to the PATH environment under Windows

Tags: windows

While installing a third-party software, it asks me to add something to the PATH environment to the operating system. How to do that under Windows 7.

Comment: I do this using [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) which is a bit easier than using the rather small Window UI

Comment: Windows 10 finally has a decent user interface for this.

Comment: Windows 10 UI picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JphSc.png

Answer (score 4):

Start > Control Panel > System > System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables

Go to the box at the bottom and scroll down to where it says: PATH
Highlight it, click edit, and append your new PATH data to the string. Be sure to add a semi-colon at the end before adding your new string. Look at the rest of the PATH string to understand this.

If you use a console or an app that depends on the path, you will have to restart it for the change to take effect

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the existing answer I think it is noteworthy to point out the registry locations. The global environment variables are stored in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

the user-specific ones are stored in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

(or `HKEY_USERS\<USER-SID>\Environment`, in case you want to modify it for other logged-on users).

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636055/how-to-modify-the-path-variable-definitely-through-the-command-line-in-windows) and the accepted answer for how to tell all running programs that you changed the environment. This is done by broadcasting a special window message.

Answer (score 1):

You could just type `"SETX" "ENV_VAR" "Value"` on command-prompt to [set new enviroment variables on Windows.](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

Comment: That is untrue. It will actually only affect the current process (usually the command processor `cmd.exe` in this case) and its sub-processes. It won't affect the system or even the user variables in any way outside that scope.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED ops, that is true, edited it to SETX command, which is permanent.

Comment: Good one, also mentioned in the answer over at SO I referenced. +1 :)

Comment: You want users to NUKE their existing path with this? Terrible idea.  They could however try `SETX PATH %PATH%;c:\new\path`

Answer (score 0):

You asked for software, so may I recommend [EnvMan](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18588/EnvMan-1-3-Windows-Environment-Variables-Manager).

I use it all the time, and it provides a nice way to manage your path. Make sure to run it as administrator.